# Concurrency conflict trying to use BufferedWriter in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

I have a threading problem of some kind outputting to a JTextArea. I have a BufferedWriter set up to write to this text area, but for some reason it is not writing to this area until the current function is done. For example, I have this code that checks a list of URLs to see if they are good or bad:

```
for( final String s : urls ){
    String sContent = IO.getURLContent( s );
    if( sContent == null ){
        writeLine( "Error " + s );
    } else {
        writeLine( "Worked " + s );
    }
}

void writeLine( String sLineText ) throws java.io.IOException {
    mbwriter.write(sLineText);
    mbwriter.newLine();
    mbwriter.flush();
}
```

The output is only occurring AFTER the loop is done, even though the writer is being flushed after every URL is checked. I tried putting the IO operation in a separate thread like this:

```
for( final String s : urls ){
SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        String sContent = IO.getURLContent( s );
            if( sContent == null ){
                writeLine( "Error " + s );
            } else {
                writeLine( "Worked " + s );
            }
        }
    }
} );
}
```

But it makes no difference, the output is still blocked until the entire loop is complete.

Note that the ENTIRE Swing interface is hung during this operation. You can't click on anything, even the window closer. The interface is completely frozen.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: And given there is no '?' in those words - what is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be expected.

Swing is a single threaded environment, that is, if you block the Event Dispatching Thread with long running process or block method calls, it will be unable to process new events posted to the Event Queue, effectively making your UI "hang"

It sounds like your first example is running within the context of the EDT and your second example is still running within the context of the EDT, but is schedule an update at some time in the future, after the EDT is able to, once again, process the Event Queue...

`invokeLater` is placing an event on the Event Queue for the EDT to process "later"

Consider using a `SwingWorker` instead, it provides the ability to run code in the background but provides methods that allow you to synchronise the updates to the EDT via it's `publish` and `process` methods

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and 
[Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

As an example...

```
public class URLWorker extends SwingWorker<List<String>, String> {

    private List<String> urls;
    private BufferedWriter bw;

    public URLWorker(List<String> urls, BufferedWriter bw) {
        this.urls = urls;
        this.bw = bw;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String result : chunks) {

            try {
                bw.write(result);
                bw.newLine();
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                firePropertyChange("error", null, ex);
            }

        }
        try {
            bw.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            firePropertyChange("error", null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(urls.size());
        for (final String s : urls) {
            String sContent = IO.getURLContent(s);
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s);
            if (sContent == null) {
                result.insert(0, "Error ");
            } else {
                result.insert(0, "Worked ");
            }
            publish(result.toString());
            results.add(result.toString());
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```